# adding esri widget results in duplicate id error

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis-js-api

I have an existing ESRI ArcGis Javascript api based application, in which the [measurement widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/widget_measurement.html) should be added.
When I try to start up this widget I receive the following errors:

1. dojo/parser::parse() error Error: Tried to register widget with id==dijit_layout_ContentPane_0 but that id is already registered
2. Error parsing in _ContentSetter#undefined Error: Tried to register widget with id==dijit_layout_ContentPane_0 but that id is already registered
3. Error undefined running custom onLoad code: This deferred has already been resolved

Html:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Measurement'">
    <div id="Measurement"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
require(["esri/IdentityManager",
    "dojo/parser",
    "user/MeasurementLoader"
], function(parser, MeasurementLoader) {
    parser.parse();
    //bootstrap other stuff

    MeasurementLoader.init({
        map: map
    });
});
```

MeasurementLoader:

```
define([
        "...",

    ],
    function(dom, ...) {
        esriConfig.defaults.geometryService = new GeometryService("http://ourarcgisserverurl");

        var
            sls = new SimpleLineSymbol("solid", new Color([195, 176, 23]), 2),
            sfs = new SimpleFillSymbol("solid", sls, null),

            init = function(options) {
                var widget = new Measurement({
                    map: options.map,
                    fillSymbol: sfs,
                    lineSymbol: sls
                        //replace by options.container later on
                }, dom.byId("Measurement"));

                widget.startup();
            };
        return {
            init: init
        };
});
```

The solution to this error should be disabling either parseOnLoad by setting `data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: false"`, when loading the arcgis library, or by removing `parser.parse()`. But neither solution does work.

Removing the `MeasurementLoader.init()` call also removes the errors, which indicates, that my code is causing a second parse call or is producing a duplicate id. Since my DOM does only contain "dijit_layout_ContentPane_0" once, I'm favoring the first option.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: [Simplified JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wr1tu4w9/) which reproduces the problem. I've removed the non-essential bits and put everything in one source file to make it clearer.

Comment: may be you have other data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"  in you app ??

Comment: Yes of course, lots. Wasn't a problem before

Comment: Is possible to create a sample Jsfiddle or anywhere.. where we can reproduce the same error?

Comment: Is your problem solved in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/barbsan/wr1tu4w9/2/)? I've added dijit modules to require list and moved `parser.parse()` to the top, but I'm not familiar with esri so I can't tell whether something is missed now.

Comment: It is, but I don't understand why bringing those dependencies into the js, creates the widget, while the parser creates the rest even without them. To me this is absolutely bonkers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I tried to solve it and it seems like there are some problem with ESRI Measurement widget.

The id `id==dijit_layout_ContentPane_0` its claiming that, it is registered that is dynamically generated by **`esri measurement widget`** itself.

Below screenshot for more details-

[image]

However it removes the error if we require all the `dijit components` on the top and move `parser.parse()` on the top.

```
"dijit/layout/BorderContainer"
"dijit/layout/ContentPane"
"dijit/layout/AccordionContainer"
"dijit/form/Button"
"dijit/form/TextBox"
```

Still I am trying to find some workaround for this, I will updated as soon as i will find anything else.

**Hoping this will help you :)**

Comment: It does solve my error for now. I'm also crawling through the dojo documentation, to find out, why the requirements solve this error.

Comment: i observed in few other samples(Mostly in ESRI samples)- Everywhere you have to "parse" on the top and you have to require all the components at the top which you are using in HTML...-- btw thanks for accepting (y) Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving:

> Error: Tried to register widget with id==dijit_layout_ContentPane_0
>   but that id is already registered

indicates that another widget of ContentPane with the same name already exists in your application.

`parseOnLoad` true indicates Dojo to apply dojo/parser to the entire body after the page is loaded. This is simple approach and works when the page contains mostly widgets and no setup logic is required after the parse.
In practice, however, many applications require setup code to run after parsing is complete and `parser.parse()` is likely what you need.